# Microsoft Hadoop Integration

Tags: .net, hadoop, sql-server-2012, qizmt

I have been reading they have now abandoned their HPC project and going for Hadoop. And that they'll be providing their own hadoop installation package that presumably will integrate with .NET more seamlessly.

Where can I get the documentation on this plan? Architecture and how to get started experimenting with it locally.

Also the other alternative to Hadoop on .NET is Qizmt from myspace. http://qizmt.myspace.com/ <-- How does it compare. It looks like a Map Reduce framework, but it seems useless without HDFS/Big table type of file system, so does it come with one?

THanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft is working on Hadoop along with HortonWorks. You can see a presentation about it [here](http://www.slideshare.net/bradsa/apache-hadoop-for-windows-server-and-windwos-azure).
I guess you'd be able to use C# via hadoop streaming but it seems the main plan is to use javascript for hadoop jobs. It is currently available in Azure. A CTP for windows server [should be available soon](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-to-add-another-preview-build-more-testers-for-hadoop-on-azure/12121)

Regarding Qizmt - I don't know much about it but a quick look at its [repository](http://code.google.com/p/qizmt/) shows just 2 committers and a GPLv3 license -I would probably not use that